Column headers move when on a different tab using replaceData()?
I've identified an issue with DT (stable: 0.33, dev: 0.33.1) for R Shiny (1.9.1) that might be resolvable through some Javascript.
Specifically, when using multiple tabs (see reprex below) if using DT::replaceData() to update a DT table with scroller on a different tabset from where a button is clicked, the first render will be correct:

But the second time the button is clicked, the headers "squish" together on the left-hand side:

This only seems to be an issue when any form of scrolling is enabled (which in this case, is the mandatory functionality) regardless of whether the scroller extension (and pagination) is used or not.  Not using the scroller does not result in this behavior.
Reprex:
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# doesn't work
 ui = fluidPage(

   tabsetPanel(
     tabPanel("button",
              actionButton("change", "Change")
              ),
     tabPanel("table",
              DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
   )

 )


# works
# ui = fluidPage(
#   
#   tabsetPanel(
#     tabPanel("button and table in one tab",
#              tags$br(),
#              actionButton("change", "Change"),
#              tags$br(),
#              DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
#   )
#   
# )

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  cars_plus = mtcars
  cars_plus$new =  sample(100, 1)
  
  rvs = reactiveValues(
    cars = cars_plus
  )
  
  
  
  table_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy("table")
  
  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(server = T, {
    
    DT::datatable(isolate(rvs$cars),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  extensions = c('Buttons'),
                  options=list(
                    buttons = list(
                      list(extend = 'colvis', text = 'Choose visible columns')
                    ),
                    dom = '<"top"B>rt<"bottom">i',
                    scrollY = '200',
                    paging = F
                  )
    )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$change,{
    
    dat = rvs$cars
    
    changer = sample(100, 1)
    
    dat[3, "new"] = changer
    
    rvs$cars = dat
    
    DT::replaceData(table_proxy, dat, rownames = F, resetPaging = F, clearSelection = "none")
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I'd suggest to file an issue here.

There are some issues with scrollY. You can avoid this by adding an event handler on shown.bs.tab which resets the width of the dataTable to 100% and calls columns.adjust():
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).css('width', '100%');
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
  });
});


library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(
    "$(document).ready(function() {
       $('a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
         $($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).css('width', '100%');
         $($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
       });
     });"
  ))),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("button",
             actionButton("change", "Change")
    ),
    tabPanel("table",
             DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  cars_plus = mtcars
  cars_plus$new =  sample(100, 1)
  
  rvs = reactiveValues(
    cars = cars_plus
  )
  
  table_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy("table")
  
  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(server = T, {
    
    DT::datatable(isolate(rvs$cars),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  extensions = c('Buttons'),
                  options=list(
                    buttons = list(
                      list(extend = 'colvis', text = 'Choose visible columns')
                    ),
                    dom = '<"top"B>rt<"bottom">i',
                    scrollY = '200',
                    paging = F
                  )
    )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$change,{
    
    dat = rvs$cars
    
    changer = sample(100, 1)
    
    dat[3, "new"] = changer
    
    rvs$cars = dat
    
    DT::replaceData(table_proxy, dat, rownames = F, resetPaging = F, clearSelection = "none")
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Excellent, I'll accept this answer. Note that by readjusting the columns with columns.adjust() the scroll position is reset.  A bit more JS can probably deal with that.
